# TFS Test Chart - How to assign the test result chart to be displayed in dashboard till the sprint end date?

Tags: testing, tfs

I want the test result chart should be displayed in dashboard till the sprint end date after that it should be removed automatically and the new sprint test chart should be displayed. The problem i am getting is, i have started the new sprint but the old sprint test chart is still displaying in the dashboard.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?  Could you add a related screenshot, how you assign the test  result chart for now?

Comment: I'm Using VSTS version 16.131.27701.1. After you done with creating test cases(test plan) you can see the option "chart" on top of your test cases then create a new chart add it to the Dashboards @PatrickLu-MSFT. Image Link [IMG]http://i67.tinypic.com/2ephe93.jpg[/IMG]